# Distance $D(A, B)$ is defined to be $D(A, B) = \inf d(a, b)$. Show that $D$ does not define a metric on the power set of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

(Distance between sets) The distance $D(A, B)$ between two
nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of a metric space $(X, d)$ is defined to be
$D(A, B) = \inf d(a, b)$ where $a$ is an element of $A$, $b$ is an element of $B$
Show that $D$ does not define a metric on the power set of $X$. (For this
reason we use another symbol, $D$, but one that still reminds us of $d$.)

Comment: $D((-1,0),(0,1)) = 0$ but $(-1,0) \neq (0,1)$.

Comment: what about $D(\phi,X)$?

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ has two different points $x\neq y$, then $A = \{x\}, B = \{x,y\}$ have $D(A,B)=0$, as $x$ is in both sets. So the axiom that distance 0 implies equal "points" does not hold.

As mentioned by others, the empty set is also problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=\mathbb R$.

Consider $A=\{0\}\subset \mathbb R$ and $B=\{\dfrac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}$

Obviously $0$ is a limit point of $B$ and hence $d(A,B)=0$ but $A\neq B$

Comment: Too complicated, and suggests that X being infinite would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is first of all not a function on $P(X)\times P(X)$.

---

If $D:P(X)\times P(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as given,

we have for $\phi,X\in P(X)$,$$D(\phi,X)=\inf\{d(a,b):a\in\phi,b\in X\}=\inf\{\}$$
and $\inf\{\}$ doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $D$ is not a function on $P(X)\times P(X)$.

Hence for any metric space $(X,d)$ the given definition of $D$ will not give you a metric on $P(X)$.